# How to use RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER and RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS with defined rabbitmq-conf.json

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I am facing an issue while trying to run RabbitMQ docker container.
It says user does not exist (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOeqq.png).

I am passing userid and password to RabbitMQ docker-compose file as environment variables during runtime.(user and password wont be fix)

[docker-compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMUKD.png)

I have created rabbitmq-conf.json as i need to use some predefined queues.

[rabbitmq-conf.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKq4O.png)

It was working fine with RabbitMQ:3.8.14-management-alpine image but not working with Rabbitmq:3.11.3-management-alpine

rabbitmq.conf file contains:-
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-conf.json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please _attach_ your `rabbitmq.conf` file, or better yet, provide _everything_ in a git repository I can clone.